# Are the table indexes used in the select on the resultset of a subquery in the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the SQL Server with more than 50 millions rows, so I have some compound indexes in my table. Indexes with 3, 4 columns. There is a situation where I really need to use a subquery in the FROM clause.

example of the structure( the index is: column2, column3, column4 ):

```
select column1 
from
    (select 
         column1, column2, column3, column4 
     from 
         myTable) as MYSUBQUERY
where 
    column2 = 99 and column3 = 999
order by 
    column4
```

The example is only to illustrate the query in the FROM. My question is generic in relation to the use of table indexes in the results of subquery in the FROM clause and any performance issues.

My question: will the compound indexes of myTable (column2, column3, column4) work in the subquery used in FROM clause? Will work like a regular select direct in the table without lose performance?

Best Regards, 
Luis

Comment: Get the execution plan and see. The subquery is trivial so the optimizer will simply fold it back into the main query. Using it is, in fact, pointless.

Comment: Hmm, in the example you gave, the `WHERE` can be pushed down, but then again the derived table isn't necessary here at all. I don't think a generic answer is possible here. When in doubt, check the plan with your actual query.

Comment: In the ExecutionPlan looks like seems to be the same plan. Running a simple test the performance seems to be the same too.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like your **previous** question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829359/do-sql-server-indexes-work-with-queries-in-the-subquery - please **DO NOT** repost the same question over and over again

Comment: Mark, I'm sorry, but I only did what you asked in the previous question: "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.

Closed 17 hours ago by marc_s"

Comment: I focused in one problem only( Excluding Lag factor ), and posted a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *declarative* language.  A `SELECT` query describes the results to be produced, not how they are produced.  The SQL query is transformed into a set of operators, which you can see as the "explain" plan.  This set is structured as a directed acyclic graph and is often called a DAG.

The optimizer optimizes this graph of operations, not the original query.  In fact, there is no such thing as a "subquery" in the DAG.

So, the subquery is irrelevant in SQL Server.  The conditions will be applied to the subquery, if the optimizer can detect that they are used and no other operations affect the results.

Other operations, such as `join`s, aggregations, and window functions could change the meaning of the query and affect whether or not the index gets used.

But for the simple example in your question, SQL Server, should use the index.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, Gordon. Analyzing the Execution Plan is really the same plan.